# Regex para introducir 2 dígitos y 4 dígitos

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo un `<input>` tipo `number` que en la entidad del formulario tiene puesto el siguiente código para que me verifique el valor:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Campo requerido")]
[RegularExpression(@"/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/", ErrorMessage = "El valor tiene que ser de dos digitos.")]
```

El problema es que la expresión regular no la tengo bien creada (creo), ya que pongo **01** y me dice que el valor es incorrecto, cuando es un `<input>` de meses y deberías poder poner del **1** al **12**.

Después tengo que hacer lo mismo con otro `<input>` que tengo por años que se puede introducir del 1960 hacia delante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error que estás sufriendo es debido a que **no debes usar** los delimitadores `/ ... /` en la expresión regular.

La anotación con la expresión regular debería ser la siguiente:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$",
    ErrorMessage = "El valor tiene que ser de dos dígitos.")]
```

Para una comprobación de este tipo deberías usar [validación por rango](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netcore-3.1) en vez de usar [expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

Puedes conseguirlo fácilmente con la siguiente anotación:

```
[Range(1, 12,
    ErrorMessage = "El valor de {0} debe estar comprendido entre {1} y {2}.")]
```

Por lo que la validación del campo de año se podría hacer con la siguiente anotación:

```
[Range(1960, 2022,
    ErrorMessage = "El valor de {0} debe estar comprendido entre {1} y {2}.")]
```

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia me ha funcionado lo de la regularexpression.